# Invalid cookie header, connection shutdown while posting data to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, httpclient

I try to post data to my google spreadsheet via googleforms with help of this code. https://github.com/FoamyGuy/GoogleFormUploadExample. Well it did not work so i modified what i knew to modify. I now arrive to access the google-spreadsheet but there is only the time-stamp posted.

The app performs well and there is no crash. my logcat looks like this:

---

> 05-05 23:09:10.329 27504-27504/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker
>   I/DocsUpload: OnCreate() 05-05 23:09:10.359
>   27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker D/Your App Name Here:
>   Setting httpPost headers 05-05 23:09:10.359
>   27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker D/Your App Name Here:
>   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HpobVoc9vFsz-II4_nmY4Hv0KseeV9TRsUzg77gqLGE/formResponse?entry.795488246=Kirtan+Loor&entry.766314875=124&entry.2032101140=9&entry.1605115542=100
>   05-05 23:09:12.809 27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker
>   W/ResponseProcessCookies: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie:
>   NID=79=CnBsvSBH-aZoGrc1NB8BQ2Yrl6nSaHOdh8VaSJZLdE89RrJu4-JN6ZnSji9X-NVgmC21BL0sNYQzxNAaN5O3GbrA44dT7WXXqVGKcM3IY86M7dPccogRgu-zsGXoBDlO;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri,
>   04-Nov-2016 21:09:14 GMT;HttpOnly". Unable to parse expires attribute:
>   Fri 05-05 23:09:12.809 27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker
>   W/ResponseProcessCookies: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie:
>   NID=79=k5mR5bFmZvd6YCj-sfkRgyS-YH_x1IGYUYASOL3GH59bRbTJoL2hOpNArB32L_sGFtgOnCfywT-4PhLbpI5B87fsyZnqKvxa8-io5nPv2z87-gbOHgnI5hiwV9qMsZUx;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 21:09:14 GMT;HttpOnly". Unable to parse expires attribute:
>   Fri 05-05 23:09:12.809 27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker
>   W/ResponseProcessCookies: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie:
>   S=spreadsheet_forms=ukSxX4pqNslybRYMiTLX1A; Domain=.docs.google.com;
>   Expires=Thu, 05-May-2016 22:09:14 GMT;
>   Path=/forms/d/1HpobVoc9vFsz-II4_nmY4Hv0KseeV9TRsUzg77gqLGE; Secure;
>   HttpOnly". Unable to parse expires attribute: Thu 05-05 23:09:12.819
>   27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker D/Your App Name Here:
>   Returning value:
>                                                                                          
>                                                                                          
>                                                                                          
>                                                                                          
>                                                                                          
>                                                                                          Vielen Dank!
>                                                                                           05-05
>   23:09:12.819 27504-32208/de.testyahoo.FL24K_Legion_Tracker
>   I/DocsUpload: 
>                                                                                  
>                                                                                  
>                                                                                  
>                                                                                  
>                                                                                  
>                                                                                  Vielen Dank!

---

I believe the error appears here: W/ResponseProcessCookies: Invalid cookie header:

I believve the connection is closed in reason of something is wrong. Curios is that if i click on the link in log cat after your app name, the thank you page from the google form appears and the data post to the spread sheet. i have no idea how to solve this. thank you for any hint in the right direction.